# React Router Dom v6: Scroll To Top on Route Change

Tags: scroll, react-router-dom, wrapper

I made a website on Reactjs and I have linked various pages using 'react-router-dom v6'. Whenever I transition from one page to another, the second page always loads on the current location instead of the top. I have tried many tutorials and solutions but they all are valid till v5 of react-router-dom.

Answer (score 8):

I solved the following issue by creating a wrapper function and wrapping it around all the routes.

Follow the following steps:

1: You need to import the following:

```
import {Routes, Route, BrowserRouter as Router, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useLayoutEffect} from 'react';
```

2: Write a wrapper function just above the "App" function:

```
const Wrapper = ({children}) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [location.pathname]);
  return children
}
```

3: Now wrap your routes within the wrapper function:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Wrapper>
    <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/Products" element={<Products/>} />
        <Route path="/Login" element={<Login/>} />
        <Route path="/Aggressive" element={<Aggressive/>} />
        <Route path="/Attendance" element={<Attendance/>} />
        <Route path="/Choking" element={<Choking/>} />
        <Route path="/EmptyCounter" element={<EmptyCounter/>} />
        <Route path="/FaceMask" element={<FaceMask/>} />
        <Route path="/Fainting" element={<Fainting/>} />
        <Route path="/Smoking" element={<Smoking/>} />
        <Route path="/SocialDistancing" element={<SocialDistancing/>} />
        <Route path="/Weapon" element={<Weapon/>} />
      </Routes>
    <Footer />
  </Wrapper>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This should solve the issue.